# SPD Update List Item - If "field" in Current List equals "Yes", then Update status in List 2

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, task-list, updatelistitems

I have a form library, with a SPD Custom Task associated with it for approvals.  The approver just has to check a box when they approve the form.  But in order for them to not get a reminder to approve the form again, they also have to approve/complete the Task.  I am trying to use the Update List Item Workflow to set the Task to "complete" when the checkbox for approve equals yes.

I start with the "If any value equals value" condition, and put my "If CurrentItem:ManagerApprove equals Yes" statement in.

Then I add the Action for **Update List Item**.  I click on the **this list** link, and put my "ManagerApprove Tasks" as the List to Update.  For the **Field**, I enter "Status" and **Value** as "Completed."  Below for **Field** under the "Find the List Item" I put "Related Content" since that is the name of the form from the "Current List", and put "Current Item:Name" for the **Value.**

This does not work though.  Any suggestions?  Would it be easier/better to create the workflow from the Task List as the Associated list, and have it update Current Item when the Approve checkbox equals Yes on the Form Library?

Thanks

Comment: Could you clarify your workflow process a bit more? I'm not sure if this approval check box is a field in your form library, or if it's a task on the task list associated witn your library.

Answer (score 1):

fuandon,
The approval check-box is a field on the form library.  The workflow process looks like: Requestor submits request form.  Manager receives a task notification via email to approve the form, which is a custom task process from Sharepoint Designer.  The manager goes to the request form, and checks the approve check-box field.  But then they also need to open the actual task and complete that too, or they will receive reminder notifications when the task expires.

I would prefer this to be a one step process, where they only need to approve the form, and not have to worry about completing the task.  I think that should be done automatically once the form is approved.  Because more often than not, they forget to complete the task, and receive the reminders emails. Then I get phone calls asking why they're receiving emails requesting approval on a form they already approved.

So I was hoping there was a workflow process that would change the status on the Task List to "Completed" once the "Approval" field on the request form equaled yes.

Does that make more sense?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the workflow so that I instead used the Task list as the associated list and had it update the Current List Item when the Approve checkbox from the form library equals yes.  But instead of using the "Update List Item" action, I just used "Set field in current item."

However, as soon as I submit a form, the status in the Task List changes to "complete" even if the Approve checkbox equals No still.  Anyone know why it's doing that?